# Django ModelForm form.is_valid is false but with no form.errors

Tags: django, modelform

I have problems with Django ModelForm, I have the situation where form.is_valid() = false but with no form.errors. That's why I'm getting no updates in the database.

This is what I have:

```
#views.py
def blog_update(request, slug):
    obj = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)
    form = BlogModelForm(request.POST or None, instance=obj)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

        form = BlogModelForm()

    template_name = 'form.html'
    context = {"form": form, "title": f"Update {obj.title}"}
    
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

```
# forms.py
class BlogModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ['title', 'slug', 'content']
```

```
# form.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %} 

<form method="POST" action="."> {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}

    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

I hope you can help me to find where the problem is. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

To get the form errors you need to check if the form is valid first. See below:

```
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)

        obj.user = request.user
        obj.save()

        form = BlogModelForm()
    else:
        print(form.errors)
```

Comment: I had try the exact same code befere and it hadn't solve the problem, Django is not showing me any result in form.errors. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, It was a tiny thing I wasn't seeing.

I has just to change form.html

Where I had

```
<form method="POST" action='.'>
```

I has just to take off the period to

```
<form method="POST" action=''>
```

And ready! Thanks a lot for your time!